# how to send large data with python through TCP? it breaks at 1452 bytes

Tags: python, tcp, connection, limit

I've been trying for more the 2 days to figure out a solution to this problem but with no results.

The connection breaks after 1452 bytes, it doesn't make any difference if i set buffer size to 1024 or 2048, as at 1452 it breaks and the data arrives to the server only partially.

The transfer works fine if i do it in localhost, but not from my pc to the server.

This below is the code.

server.py

```
 import socketserver

class Handler_TCPServer(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """ tcp class"""

    def handle(self):
        # self.request - TCP csocket connected to the client

        self.data_received = b""
        while True:
            part = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            print(len(part))
            self.data_received += part
            if len(part) < 1024:
                break
        print("{} sent: ".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print("Data", self.data_received)



        # send back ACK for data arrival confirmation
        self.request.sendall("ACK from TCP server".encode())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "", 5002

    # Ini the TCP server object, bind it to the * on 5002 port
    tcp_server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), Handler_TCPServer)

    # Activate the TCP server
    # To abort the TCP server press Ctrl-C
    tcp_server.serve_forever()
```

and client.py

```
import socket
import pickle

host_ip, server_port = "MYSERVERIP", 5002

class TCP_client:
    def handle(self, data_bytes):
        # Initialize a TCP client socket using a SOCK_STREAM
        tcp_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            # Establish connection to the TCP server and exchange data
            tcp_client.connect((host_ip, server_port))
            tcp_client.sendall(data_bytes)

            # Read data from the TCP server and close the connection
            received = tcp_client.recv(1024)
        finally:
            tcp_client.close()

        print("Bytes Sent:  {}".format(data_bytes))
        print("Bytes Received {}".format(received.decode()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tcp = TCP_client()

    data = {"Name": "Luke", "age": 25, "height": 175}
    data_bytes = pickle.dumps(data)
    tcp.handle(data_bytes)
```

Comment: why do you check `if len(part) < 1024` after `.strip()` ? You could receive `1024` and you should receive next part but you strip some data and you thing that it is end of data.

Comment: What do you mean with "it breaks". Do you get a connection close signaled? I don't even see a handler for that.

Comment: The most likely thing is you get the data trough multiple read calls instead of in a single one. This can always happen, since TCP is a stream and not packets.